# Expected expression before ')' token

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm having problems with a program I'm trying to make in Objective-C.

I have a method that I'm *trying* in my MainViewController.m that is as follows.

```
- (void)updateLabels:(NSString *)text :(BOOL)isOn; 
{
[self setNameLabel:(text *); 
if (isOn)
 [self setOnLabel:(ON *);
else
  [self setOnLabel:(OFF *); 
}
```

My goal should be obvious from this code.  I'm problably doing something terribly wrong to get the error message `Expected expression before ')' token`.

I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3):

This looks more like what you are trying to do, that is assign text to a label and then toggle whether its ON or OFF

```
#define ON YES
#define OFF NO
    - (void)updateLabels:(NSString *)text isOn:(BOOL)
        {
        [self setNameLabel:text]; 
        if (isOn)
         [self setOnLabel:ON];
        else
          [self setOnLabel:OFF]; 
        }
```

Comment: Still got the semicolon at the end of the method declaration that is raising the error.

Answer (score 2):

A couple problems here. First, you don't need that semicolon. Second, you don't need to pass pointers for `ON` and `OFF`:

```
- (void)updateLabelsWithText:(NSString *)text AndOnState:(BOOL)isOn {
    [self setNameLabel: text]; 
    if(isOn)
        [self setOnLabel:@"ON"];
    else
        [self setOnLabel:@"OFF"];
}
```

Comment: The superfluous semicolon is actually legal believe it or not.

Answer (score -1):

It should be:

```
 - (void)updateLabels:(NSString *)text status:(BOOL) isOn {
    ...
```

You need to remove the semi-colon after the method declaration. The second and subsequent parameters need both a field name (status) and a variable to put the value in (isOn).

In the interface declaration you swap the opening bracket for a semi-colon like this:

```
 - (void)updateLabels:(NSString *)text status:(BOOL) isOn;
```

Then calling it would look like this:

```
[... updateLabels:@"My label text" status:YES];
```

Comment: -1 You don't need to remove the semicolon (believe it or not) and you can have a bare colon in a selector.

Comment: Oh, didn't know that. Whats the effect of leaving the semi-colon in and using bare colons in selectors? I'm presuming they would be classified as a less than desirable practice given I've not seen it done in any examples and books I've looked at :-)

Comment: Clarkson: You're right, you *should* name all the parameters in the selector, and you'll rarely see code that doesn't.